# Booting CD in laptop with or without HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, boot, bios

My friend have this [*NEO Laptop Basic B5106*](http://neo.com.ph/download-basic-series-drivers/cat_view/10-basic-series/153-basic-b5106-n), about a year old. I taught her how to format and now she constantly formatted it because it always fail to boot or there's a *mass amount of computer viruses* that she can't remove. This time, it can't now boot up successfully. It will just stop after the initial BIOS background(?). She tried to format it but with no luck, it won't work. In her conclusion, it looks like it has already a HDD problem or the cable(SATA) connected to Mobo.

List of problems according to her `(we're only communicating in chat)`:

1. HDD cannot read properly `(seems a hardware problem for me)`
2. When HDD is attached, OS cannot be read properly(?)
3. When the HDD is not attached, booting from CD works but no way to format it because laptop will freeze if she return it back while it is turned ON.

What I told her to try:

1. Arrange boot priority order in BIOS setup (make sure CD-ROM is on top)
2. Remove and return back HDD while laptop is ON during booting of OS from CD.
   `(This one works a little bit but it fails when the HDD returned back)`
3. Make sure all the wires are properly plugged in.

All of my recommendations won't work. Please suggest any ways we can try? Thanks!

Comment: Is she pressing the `Boot Options` key?  F12 or F10.  And can she access the BIOS to do what you said about changing the boot order?

Comment: Of course. its F2 on her laptop.

Comment: @mr5 - Sounds like the hdd should be replaced and the operating system reinstalled.  This is likely something you will have to do for your friend.

Comment: No, F2 is the BIOS Setup usually.  I'm asking about manually selecting the boot options.  Or is her boot options F2?  I could be mistaken and if so I apologize

Comment: @Ramhound the system has no warning about that like SMART warnings or similar? should we really need to replace it?

Comment: @TKEyi60 I don't get what you mean by `boot options` and `accessing BIOS` but all we can press to go there is F2?

Comment: Why downvote? I was just asking for any suggestions? **please tell me what have I done wrong**

Comment: @mr5 - I don't even know what operating system we are dealing with the hardware wasn't picked up in a Google search.  I came to the conclusion it was the HDD based on the reported problems.  Its not clear if you have reinstalled the operating system to solve the most recent problem.  If the laptop won't boot to to the cd with the hdd installed this only confirm its the hdd.

Comment: @Ramhound it has Windows 7 installed on it. Sorry a typo in the name.

Comment: To clarify: If she can boot from CD fine, but booting or reinstalling an OS isn't working, it sounds like the hard drive is the problem.  Can she try connecting the hard drive to another computer (using something like SATA-to-USB) and format that way?  If something goes wrong there, you can be fairly certain it is a hard drive related problem.

Comment: @mellowmaroon , Thanks for the time reading this, but she already decided to buy a new HDD. Better if it is a HDD problem else, hope she will not blame me for this. :)

Comment: Did the old (possibly broken) HDD work on another computer? If not that you have a clear indication of a broken drive.

Answer (score -3):

Press <kbd>F8</kbd> and select `Boot from CD-ROM`.